# transaction generation failed: invalid chain ID (ERDPY)

Tags: command-line-interface, blockchain, web3py, multiversx, erdpy

I'm trying to send a bulk transaction on the elrond devnet but i still have an error :

I'm following this doc -> [Click here to see it](https://%20https://docs.elrond.com/sdk-and-tools/erdpy/sending-bulk-transactions/#step-1-prepare-the-pem-file)

The script is working but he give me a log talking about an invalid chain id -> [https://gateway.elrond.com/transaction/send]: {'data': None, 'error': 'transaction generation failed: invalid chain ID', 'code': 'internal_issue'}
Transaction sent with nonce 45 and backed up to bon-mission-tx-45.json.

So i've updated my config has show [here](https://docs.elrond.com/sdk-and-tools/erdpy/configuring-erdpy/) for the devnet and I still have the same error.

Does somebody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either set a global setting to reuse the chain-ID without explicitly specifying it in the `mxpy tx` command, or pass it explicitly. I'll detail below:

**First variant** is to run an mxpy config to specify the default proxy or the chain id to use if not specified in the mxpy tx body, like so:

```
mxpy config set chainID D
mxpy config set proxy https://devnet-gateway.multiversx.com
```

See details here: https://docs.elrond.com/sdk-and-tools/erdpy/configuring-erdpy/#docsNav

**Second variant** is to append `--chain=$CHAIN_ID` to your mxpy tx generation script like this:

```
function send-bulk-tx {
  for transaction in "${TRANSACTIONS[@]}"; do
    set -- $transaction
    mxpy --verbose tx new --send --outfile="bon-mission-tx-$NONCE.json" --pem=$PEM_FILE --nonce=$NONCE --receiver=$1 --value="$2$DENOMINATION" --gas-limit=50000 --proxy=$PROXY --chain=$CHAIN_ID
    echo "Transaction sent with nonce $NONCE and backed up to bon-mission-tx-$NONCE.json."
    (( NONCE++ ))
  done
}
```

and declare your new variable as `CHAIN_ID=D` besides the `PROXY` variable in your `.sh` file.