# Invalid chain ID after passing --chain=D to mxpy

Tags: multiversx, erdpy

I try to deploy a contract and it works fine on Testnet, but changing `--chain=D` gives an invalid chain ID. Why?

The sent command is this:

```
mxpy --verbose contract deploy \
    --project=${PROJECT} \
    --recall-nonce \
    --pem=${ALICE} \
    --gas-limit=6000000 \
    --arguments 0 \
    --send \
    --outfile="deploy-devnet.interaction.json" \
    --chain=D
```

Related question:

- [transaction generation failed: invalid chain ID (ERDPY)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74005644/transaction-generation-failed-invalid-chain-id-erdpy)

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
--proxy=https://devnet-api.multiversx.com
```

solves the problem.